# Default Anti forgery disabling Response Caching in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement response caching and disabling default anti forgery behaviour on certain actions, but on every request I get "

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery[8]
>   The 'Cache-Control' and 'Pragma' headers have been overridden and set
>   to 'no-cache, no-store' and 'no-cache' respectively to prevent caching
>   of this response. Any response that uses antiforgery should not be
>   cached.

I define *IgnoreAntiforgeryToken* on the action. Is there another way to turn off the default anti forgery?

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .
    .
    .
    services.AddResponseCaching();

    services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.CacheProfiles.Add("Default",
                    new CacheProfile()
                    {
                        Duration = 240
                    });
                options.CacheProfiles.Add("NoCache",
                    new CacheProfile()
                    {
                        Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None,
                        NoStore = true
                    });
            })
            .AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    .
    .
    .
    app.UseResponseCaching();
}
```

**Controller.cs**:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Default", VaryByQueryKeys = new string[] { "id" })]
[HttpGet("/Shop/Category/{id:int}", Name = "Category")]
public IActionResult Category(int id)
{
    var result = this.AppHelper.ModelHelper.GetCategoryWrap(id);

    return View(result);
}
```

Comment: iirc `IgnoreAntiforgerToken` attribute is for call backs (when the form is posted back to the webserver).. It's the antiforgery token is probably added cause you have a form inside your view. In this case the response should not be cashed, otherwise the antiforgery tokens don't work. You should use ` asp-antiforgery="false"` tag helper on the `<form>` tag to disable it on a per-form basis

Answer (score 0):

When generating a form in the View set `antiforgery` param to false

```
using (Html.BeginForm(
    "MyAction",
    "MyController",
    null,
    FormMethod.Post,
    false, //<--this
    new { if = "myForm", @class="mycssclass" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `asp-antiforgery` tag helper in form code

```
<form action="" method="post" asp-antiforgery="false">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="remarks">enter remarks</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="remarks" rows="3" name="remarks">
            @if (videoViewModel.Remarks != null) {
                @videoViewModel.Remarks
            }
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```